# Spring Web App - Cannot run application after adding annotations of the database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, database-connection

I'm trying to connect a web app (using Spring MVC and Eclipse Java EE IDE) to a database (using MySQL).

I've configured the connection (at uni we are using Hibernate) like this (Location: Java resources > src/main/resources):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http: // www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http: // www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://   www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http: / / www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http ://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http ://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http ://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http ://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
                    http ://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                    http ://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
                    http ://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                    http ://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
                    http ://www.springframework.org/schema/tx   
                    http ://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd">

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <!-- Properties -->
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners">false</prop>
            <!--<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>-->
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <!-- Mappings -->
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>ar.edu.grupoesfera.cursospring.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql:// localhost:(port)/ my_database" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
    <!-- <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:db_aplicacion" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" /> -->
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

(The commented parts are there because at first we were working in memory, but now we have to connect to the database).
I did the same for test-hibernateContext.xml in src/test/resources.

This is the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http : / /maven.apache. org/POM/4.0.0"            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http : / / maven.apache. org/POM/4.0.0 http ://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Project</groupId>
<artifactId>Project</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.19.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

When I change all that configuration, the project runs perfectly fine... but after I add annotations in one of the classes of the project (Product), the app stops running.
Here is the Product.class:

```
package ar.edu.grupoesfera.cursospring.model;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@Entity
@Table (name = "Product")
public class Product implements Comparable<Product>{ 

@Id
@Column (name = "Id_Product")
private Integer id;
@Column (name = "Nom_Product")
private String nameProduct;
@Column (name = "Desc_Product")
private String description;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idColor")
private Color color;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idSize")
private Size size;

@Column (name = "Price_Product")
private Float price;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idCategory")
private Category category;

@Column (name = "Img_Product")
private MultipartFile imgproduct;
@Column (name = "Name_Img_Product")
private String nameimg;
@Column (name = "New_Product")
private String newP;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public Integer setId(Integer id) {
    return this.id = id;
}
public String getNameProduct() {
    return NameProduct;
}
public void setNameProduct(String nameProduct) {
    this.nameProducto = nameProduct;
}
public Color getColor() {
    return color;
}
public void setColor(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
}
public Size getSize() {
    return size;
}
public void setTalle(Talle talle) {
    this.talle = talle;
}
public Float getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(Float price) {
    this.price = price;
}
public Category getCategory() {
    return category;
}
public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public MultipartFile getImgproduct() {
    return imgproduct;
}
public void setImgproduct(MultipartFile imgproduct) {
    this.imgproduct = imgproduct;
}
public String getNameimg() {
    return nameimg;
}
public void setNameimg(String nameimg) {
    this.nameimg = nameimg;
}
public String getNew() {
    return new;
}
public void setNewP(String newP) {
    this.newP = newP;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Product other = (Product) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Product o) {
    return this.id.compareTo(o.id);
}

}
```

Any idea if just adding these annotations is what may be causing that I can't run the app? (it gives error 404) I mean.. there has to be some way, because I obviously need them to continue with the database, but I've been researching and I have no idea what's going on.

Note: I still don't have anything in dao package.

Edit: This is the controller for that particular class (I have many) and that part of the project:

```
package ar.edu.grupoesfera.cursospring.controladores;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import ar.edu.grupoesfera.cursospring.modelo.Categoria;
import ar.edu.grupoesfera.cursospring.modelo.ColeccionCategoria;
import ar.edu.grupoesfera.cursospring.modelo.ColeccionColor;
//import ar.edu.grupoesfera.cursospring.modelo.ColeccionProducto;
import ar.edu.grupoesfera.cursospring.modelo.ColeccionTalle;
import ar.edu.grupoesfera.cursospring.modelo.Color;
import ar.edu.grupoesfera.cursospring.modelo.Producto;
//import ar.edu.grupoesfera.cursospring.modelo.Stock;
import ar.edu.grupoesfera.cursospring.modelo.Talle;
import ar.edu.grupoesfera.cursospring.modelo.ValidadorProducto;
import ar.edu.grupoesfera.cursospring.servicios.ProductoServicio;
import ar.edu.grupoesfera.cursospring.servicios.StockServicio;

@RestController
@MultipartConfig
public class ProductController extends HttpServlet{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Inject
    private ProductService productService;
    private StockService stockService;

//New product
@RequestMapping (value = "/newProductForm")
public ModelAndView newProductForm(@ModelAttribute("product")Product product){
    CategoryCollection categorias = ColeccionCategoria.getInstance();
    ColorCollection colores = ColeccionColor.getInstance();
    SizeCollection talles = ColeccionTalle.getInstance();
    ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
    modelo.put("categorias", categorias.listCategory());
    modelo.put("colores", colores.listColor());
    modelo.put("talles", talles.listSize());
    return new ModelAndView ("newProductForm", model);
}

@RequestMapping (value = "/newProductFormConfirm")
public ModelAndView newProductFormConfirm (@ModelAttribute("product")Product product, BindingResult result){
    String info;
    CategoryCollection categorias = ColeccionCategoria.getInstance();
    ColorCollection colores = ColeccionColor.getInstance();
    SizeCollection talles = ColeccionTalle.getInstance();
    ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
    modelo.put("categorias", categorias.listCategory());
    modelo.put("colores", colores.listColor());
    modelo.put("talles", talles.listSize());
    ValidateProduct validateproduct = new ValidateProduct();
    validateproduct.validate(product, result);
      if (result.hasErrors()) {
          return new ModelAndView ("newProductFormConfirm", model);
          }
    try{
        productService.newProduct(product);
    info="Success";
    }catch(Exception e){
        productService.saveExistingProduct(product);
        info= e.getMessage();
    }
    String imgPath ="images/products"+"/"+product.getImgproduct().getOriginalFilename();
    modelo.put("info", info);
    modelo.put("imdPath", imgPath);
    return new ModelAndView ("newProductFormConfirm", model);
}

//List of products
@RequestMapping (value = "/listProducts")
public ModelAndView listProducts(@ModelAttribute("product")Product product){
    ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
    modelo.put("productService", productService.listProducts());
    return new ModelAndView ("listProducts", model);
}

//Getters and Setters for the services

}
```

Comment: 404 is nothing to do with Hibernate, show your controller

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the post